# Do we have to use Cognito for Dynamodb access?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Upgrading some legacy code using the old SDK, I would access dynamoDB using an AWS_KEY and Secret_KEY packaged in credentials that were then given to an AWSDynamoDbClient object. In version 2.0 of the SDK this client object is no longer available in AWSDynamoDB.h. All the documentation now points to Cognito for authentication so is the old way of access deprecated and the Keys not used anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), the service takes care of all the steps necessary to create a unique identifier for your app’s users and retrieve temporary, limited privilege AWS credentials. This means that you can follow security best practices, and use these temporary, limited privilege credentials instead of having to hardcode credentials into your app.

You can still use `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` with `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider`, but we discourage its use in production apps for security concerns.